# How to add ActionBar tabs in monodroid or java

Tags: android, android-actionbar, xamarin.android

I want to know how can I add some tabs to my actionbar using mono for android?
I need 3 tabs that each one keep an activity and a layout and the swipe should be enabled :)
Is it possible? If not how can I do that with java?

Comment: I don't use Mono but this appears to be relevant to what you're asking: http://fizzylogic.nl/2012/03/05/mono-for-android-by-example-the-action-bar/

Comment: Oh thanks it help a lot but how is it possible to have tabs in actionbar?

Comment: Scroll down to the section titled "Working with tabs" and it has a sample.  Once again, I don't use Mono but the code looks very similar to the equivalent Java so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

[Xamarin](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/HelloTabsICS) provides some samples on how to accomplish this on `ICS`.